# Unable to install wsgiref in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, wsgiref

I can't install wsgiref in python 3. I got these errors.
I am using python 3, but I can't install wsgiref 
I tried `pip install wsgiref` and `pip install wsgiref==0.1.2`

````
E:\CodeWork\Machine Learning\SWATI-The-Assistant-master\SWATI-The-Assistant-master>pip install wsgiref==0.1.2
Collecting wsgiref==0.1.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/9e/309259ce8dff8c596e8c26df86dbc4e848b9249fd36797fd60be456f03fc/wsgiref-0.1.2.zip
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h2ydr_0e\\wsgiref\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h2ydr_0e\\wsgiref\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h2ydr_0e\wsgiref\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h2ydr_0e\wsgiref\
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h2ydr_0e\wsgiref\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ez_setup
      File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h2ydr_0e\wsgiref\ez_setup\__init__.py", line 170
        print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed.")?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Answer (score 5):

The reason the pip 3 install is erroring is the syntax of one of the print statements in the setup process is old python 2 style with no parentheses. The good news is that wsgiref is already included in the python 3 library by default. Fire up a python 3 shell and try typing 'import wsgiref', that should succeed with no error.